# jupyter_contrib_nbextensions tab not showing for large notebooks

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I just installed `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`. However, I could see the navigator tab on only on the small notebooks. Large notebook files do not contain the tab. It is not in the edit tab either.

Would anyone be able to help me on this issue.

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Could you, please, provide example files created before and after installing `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`? Something must have changed in it's Technical Information in json...

Comment: Its only for large notebooks. Sorry, I just changed the question. Thanks